# How to draw a trail line of all locations depending gps when moving around keeping the points array of locations not too big to keep performance?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, google-maps

I want to draw a trail line when moving with my phone device similar to how it does in Samsung health application when walking/running/hiking.

In my application I store each new location to array and draw a trail line depending on this array of locations.  the problem is that the array of locations size soon will get very big.

I wonder what for example in Samsung health or other applications they are doing with that problem? in one hand I want to keep the drawn trail line until the user stop/finish the current session in the other hand I don't want to make the array of locations too big so it will make the performance a problem.

At the top of the activity:

```
private var points: ArrayList<LatLng>? = null
private var line: Polyline? = null
```

inside onCreate

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        points = ArrayList()
}
```

onMapReady

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

        mMap.uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = false

        try {
            mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = false
            mMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true

            line = mMap.addPolyline(PolylineOptions())

        } catch (e: SecurityException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

the initializeMapWithLocation method where I'm adding the locations each time the new location to the points array.

```
private fun initializeMapWithLocation(userLocation: LatLng) {

        mMap.uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = false

        try {
            mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = false
            mMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true

            val selectedMarkerType = MarkerType.CUSTOM_2

            val markerIcon = if (selectedMarkerType == MarkerType.DEFAULT) {
                BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker()
            } else {
                val originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, selectedMarkerType.resourceId)
                val width = (originalBitmap.width * selectedMarkerType.scale).toInt()
                val height = (originalBitmap.height * selectedMarkerType.scale).toInt()
                val scaledMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, width, height, false)
                BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(scaledMarker)
            }

            if (marker == null) {
                // Create a new marker if it doesn't exist yet
                marker = mMap.addMarker(
                    MarkerOptions()
                        .position(userLocation)
                        .icon(markerIcon)
                        .title("Marker Title")
                )

                // Inflate the custom info window layout
                val infoWindowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null)

                // Set the custom info window as the tag of the marker
                marker?.tag = infoWindowView

                // Set the custom InfoWindow adapter for the marker
                mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(CustomInfoWindowAdapter())
            } else {
                // Set the new position of the existing marker
                updateMarkerPosition(userLocation)

                if (points != null) {
                    points!!.add(userLocation)
                    line?.points = points as ArrayList<LatLng>
                } else {
                    // Initialize the points list if it's null
                    points = ArrayList()
                    points!!.add(userLocation)
                }

                // Get the custom info window layout from the marker's tag
                val infoWindowView = marker?.tag as View

                // Find the TextViews in the custom layout
                val latitudeTextView = infoWindowView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.latitudeTextView)
                val longitudeTextView = infoWindowView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.longitudeTextView)

                // Set the latitude and longitude values in the InfoWindow
                latitudeTextView.text = "Latitude: ${userLocation.latitude}"
                longitudeTextView.text = "Longitude: ${userLocation.longitude}"

                // Show the info window
                marker?.showInfoWindow()
            }

            if (!initialZoomCompleted) {
                val initialZoom = 5.0F
                val targetZoom = 16.0F
                val zoomSpeed = 500
                animateZoomIn(userLocation, initialZoom, targetZoom, zoomSpeed, false)
                initialZoomCompleted = true
            }
        } catch (e: SecurityException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

I'm using and calling the method initializeMapWithLocation  before the onCreate at the top

```
private val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            locationResult.lastLocation?.let { location ->
                // Handle the new location here
                val newLocation = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                initializeMapWithLocation(newLocation)
                loadingProgressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                loadingMapTextView.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bunch of different ways you can do this.  The basic idea is you want to filter the points-  you want to keep only a subset of points.  A few basic ways to do that are:

Time based-  keep only 1 point per X seconds/minutes.  That will reduce repeated points.  You don't normally really care about a second by second breakdown of location (and the GPS is noisy enough for that to be useless anyway).

Location based-  keep only points that are Y meters away or more from a previous point.  This is pretty much a requirement anyway, since GPS is noisy and will almost never report the same location exactly twice, even if standing still.

Dropping redundant data-   if you have a point A at time 1 and a point B at time 2 and C at time 3 and A,B, and C are all in a line (again since the data is noisy if they're close to in a line)-  drop B.  It's redundant to knowing A and C.

Dropping obvious mistakes-  you'll occasionally get a GPS reading that's just off.  This is very obvious in city centers and mountains, where signal bounces will show random readings blocks off.  These should be detected and dropped.  An easy way to detect it is if it makes no sense location wise with previous and next points-  it would require a sudden change in direction and speed.

You can get fancier than this as well, but these are some easy techniques to code (especially the first 2).

Comment: Great answer @Gabe Sechan! I'd only add that there are tools out there that might help with simplifying noisy geometries, e.g. [`@turf/simplify` in NodeJS](https://turfjs.org/docs/#simplify). Turf is also [ported to Java](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/tree/main/services-turf). I suppose Kotlin is also supported (?).