# Trying to use Polyline to draw a trail line and it was working but after adding more changes it's not drawing anymore. what can cause it?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, google-maps

This is my code and it's a bit long so i put it in pastebin.com: https://pastebin.com/CnqxxemT

The marker is showing fine and also moving along with the device.

The only thing that is not working is the draw line trail.
The line trail was drawn before I added the next methods at the bottom:

processing location data:

```
private fun processLocationData(newLocation: LatLng, time: Long) {
        // Filter based on time (keep only one point per X seconds)
        val filteredPoints = filterLocationByTime(time)

        // Filter based on distance (keep points that are Y meters apart)
        val filteredPoints2 = filterLocationByDistance(newLocation)

        // Combine the filtered data
        val combinedPoints = combineLocationData(filteredPoints, filteredPoints2)

        // Update the map and your data structures
        updateMapAndData(combinedPoints, newLocation)
    }
```

filtering by time:

```
    private fun filterLocationByTime(time: Long): ArrayList<LocationData> {
        val filteredPoints = ArrayList<LocationData>()

        if (points.isNotEmpty()) {
            val lastTime = points.last().time

            if (time - lastTime >= LOCATION_EXPIRATION_TIME_MS) {
                filteredPoints.add(points.last())
                filteredPoints.add(LocationData(LatLng(time.toDouble(), 0.0), time))
            }
        }

        return filteredPoints
    }
```

filtering by distance:

```
    private fun filterLocationByDistance(newLocation: LatLng): ArrayList<LocationData> {
        val filteredPoints = ArrayList<LocationData>()

        if (points.isNotEmpty()) {
            val lastLocation = points.last()
            val distance = calculateDistance(newLocation, lastLocation.latLng)

            if (distance >= MIN_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD) {
                filteredPoints.add(LocationData(newLocation, System.currentTimeMillis()))
            }
        } else {
            filteredPoints.add(LocationData(newLocation, System.currentTimeMillis()))
        }

        return filteredPoints
    }
```

calculating distance:

```
    private fun calculateDistance(pointA: LatLng, pointB: LatLng): Double {
        val radiusOfEarth = 6371 // Earth's radius in kilometers

        val lat1 = Math.toRadians(pointA.latitude)
        val lon1 = Math.toRadians(pointA.longitude)
        val lat2 = Math.toRadians(pointB.latitude)
        val lon2 = Math.toRadians(pointB.longitude)

        val dLat = lat2 - lat1
        val dLon = lon2 - lon1

        val a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
                Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) *
                Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)

        val c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a))

        val distance = radiusOfEarth * c
        return distance
    }
```

combining:

```
    private fun combineLocationData(filteredPoints1: ArrayList<LocationData>, filteredPoints2: ArrayList<LocationData>): ArrayList<LocationData> {
        // Merge the two filtered lists, removing redundant data
        val combinedPoints = ArrayList<LocationData>()
        combinedPoints.addAll(filteredPoints1)
        combinedPoints.addAll(filteredPoints2)
        return combinedPoints.distinctBy { it.latLng }.toCollection(ArrayList())
    }
```

updating map:

```
    private fun updateMapAndData(combinedPoints: ArrayList<LocationData>, newLocation: LatLng) {
        // Replace the old points with the filtered points
        points.clear()
        points.addAll(combinedPoints)
        points.add(LocationData(newLocation, System.currentTimeMillis())) // Assuming you want the current time

        // Update the Polyline on the map with the combined points
        line?.points = points.map { it.latLng } // Extract LatLng from LocationData

        // Continue with other map and data-related operations
    }
```

I used a break point and it does getting to the lines in the onMapReady function:

```
line = mMap.addPolyline(PolylineOptions())
```

it also getting to the lines in the method initializeMapWithLocation:

```
val userLocationData = LocationData(userLocation, System.currentTimeMillis())
 points.add(userLocationData)
 line?.points = points.map { it.latLng }
```

and I see that points is not empty and that line have values but it's not drawing anything.

this is my follow up question to my older question: I could successfully draw the trail line but after updating the activity with the new methods it's not drawing/showing the line anymore.

[How to draw a trail line of all locations depending gps when moving around keeping the points array of locations not too big to keep performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77386419/how-to-draw-a-trail-line-of-all-locations-depending-gps-when-moving-around-keepi)